# How to Setup Laravel using docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, nginx

I want to setup my laravel project using docker can you please tell me how to setup everything for the same. As before I have not to work on Docker for any project.

I want to use Php-fpm, Nginx or apache2 any one Database MySQL

Comment: This question is too broad for anyone to help.

Comment: It definitely is broad.  I would start using the following tutorial and come back if you have a more focused question. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose#:~:text=Docker%20Compose%20offers%20an%20efficient,database%2C%20all%20inside%20Docker%20containers.

Comment: Thank you, I will go through the above

Comment: I have follow the digital ocean link after all setup I am getting this error
https://prnt.sc/ugkfqy